# Laravel 4 validation sometimes passes when it should fail

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload a file with Laravel 4, but I just can't get the validation to work properly.

I'm testing it by sending a JPEG image, a PNG image, and a MP3 file. My code is as follows:

```
$data  = ['anexo' => Input::file('anexo')];
$rules = ['anexo' => 'mimes:jpeg'];

$validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if ($validation->fails())
{
    // PNG fails: OK
}
else
{
    // JPEG passes: OK
    // MP3 passes: WTF?
}

// Let's see what the files looks like
var_dump($data);
```

Here are the *var_dump()* for each file:

```
// JPEG
array (size=1)
  'anexo' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
      private 'test' => boolean false
      private 'originalName' => string 'ARTcast.jpg' (length=11)
      private 'mimeType' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      private 'size' => int 310177
      private 'error' => int 0

// PNG
array (size=1)
  'anexo' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
      private 'test' => boolean false
      private 'originalName' => string '1280x800.png' (length=12)
      private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      private 'size' => int 426169
      private 'error' => int 0

// MP3
array (size=1)
  'anexo' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
      private 'test' => boolean false
      private 'originalName' => string '05 - Lado B Lado A.mp3' (length=22)
      private 'mimeType' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
      private 'size' => int 0
      private 'error' => int 1
```

Any clue of what I am missing there?

Comment: Did  you notice that the `mp3` file upload returned an `error = 1` which normally means that `post_max_size` and/or  `upload_max_filesize` are set to low for that single file or the sum of all 3 file sizes, in `php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @RiggsFolly. To be completely honest, I realized that by the time I was clicking the submit button here at SO. But I decided to post my question anyways, so that it could help future me or others. I'm still trying to work on a solution for this, and will share it here as soon as I get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: Is it me, or Laravel really should detect that kind of thing? I mean, how can the validation pass if the file's got an error? :/

Comment: You create the validation, not Laravel. You will have to add that rule to your rules.

Comment: Little tip: you shouldn't rely JUST on mime type, it could be crafted. For example I could say the mine type is "image/jpeg" and send a PHP file. Always check the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for that. As @RiggsFolly has noticed, there was an error with my uploaded file (it exceeded *php.ini* size limits). As I was strictly looking to the `mimeType` value, I couldn't realize the `"error" => int 1` over there.

So here's a solution, in case someone run into the same mistake in the future. Also, I have found this `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\UploadException` exception that you might be using to inform the system and perhaps trap it within your *globals.php* or somewhere else.

```
$file = Input::file('input_name')

// checks for file upload errors
if (!$file->isValid())
{
    throw new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\UploadException(
        $file->getErrorMessage(),
        $file->getError());
}

// continues with validation
$data  = ['input_name' => $file];
$rules = ['input_name' => 'mimes:jpeg'];

$validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if($validation->fails())
{
    // proceed with normal error treatment
}
```

Again, notice that **Laravel doesn't check for upload errors when validating**, you must do it manually.